# How do you elegantly import AWS - Lambda in Typescript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, types, aws-lambda

I am building a typescript project on aws lambda. As `aws-sdk` comes with type definitions already I would expect it also to hold a definition for aws lambda. But I seem to have to install `@types/aws-lambda` separately for it to work.

```
//import { Lambda } from "aws-sdk";
import { Context } from "aws-lambda";

module.exports.hello = async (event:any, context:Context) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };
};
```

I would expect something like this being possible:

```
import { Lambda } from "aws-sdk";

module.exports.hello = async (event:any, context:Lambda.Context) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };
};
```

but it is not ;)

So How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at the source of aws-sdk?  I can think of no reason to expect that the structures that are relevant inside a Lambda function would also be relevant to the SDK.  They may be there, it just isn't intuitive to me why they would ever be useful, because the SDK's interactions face the wrong direction (for lack of a better term).

Answer (score 5):

The `aws-sdk` does not contain the types for lambda. So you will need both `aws-sdk` and `@types/aws-lambda` unfortunately. Also I would suggest to declare the `@types/aws-lambda` in the `devDependencies` of your `package.json`.

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { Context } from "aws-lambda";

module.exports.hello = async (event:any, context:Context) => {
  // eg. if you need a DynamoDB client
  // const docClient: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly only import the type definition

```
import type { Context } from "aws-lambda";
```

Comment: This answer is not exactly answering the question of the OP. He requested explanation related to the `aws-sdk` and, while your answer is technically correct, it doesn't help the OP to understand the problem and the solution.